# echo statement displayed on front end

Tags: plugins

Good day for all

I really searched SE for something like this but found nothing related.

It is a noob question really but getting answered will make me comfortable with myself :)

After setting the header section of a test plugin file I just put an echo statement.

When I activate the plugin the string of the echo gets displayed on the admin dashboard page as well as on the home page.

Is this common sense on WP or am I missing something ?

thank you a lot.

Comment: What else did you expect?

Comment: i expected the state of the plugin to be changed to activated but not the contents to be shown on the front page and the dashboard . if you put ae echo on the index.php on lets say the akismet plugin it wont show anywhere.

Comment: Plugins are just PHP files. When they are included their code is interpreted.

Comment: yes i think that wp searches for the file that contains the header section and includes it on at least front page and admin page !!

Comment: There are conditions. If the condition says that you can show the echo on admin area as well as on the homepage then it'll.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is common sense and you are missing something ;)

Plugins are just away to add code to wordpress, by default they are not inferior or restricted in any way more then then core code. Just another file(s) that wordpress includes on startup.

It is your job as a plugin developer to restrict the execution of your code to specific area/context, and you do it by hooking your code on the relevant actions and filters.

Comment: +1. The OP might want to visit the Codex to read more the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)